# Java Mail: Inline Image is not shown in email

Tags: java, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

I am trying to add inline image like this:
**Static folder location: resources-> static**

```
MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                messageHelper.setTo(recipientList);
                messageHelper.setFrom(fromEmail);
                messageHelper.setSubject(emailInfo.getSubject());
                //ClassPathResource image = new ClassPathResource("static/pin.png");
                FileSystemResource image = new FileSystemResource(new File("static/pin.png"));
    
    
               messageHelper.addInline("pin_image",image);
    
                messageHelper.setText(body, true);
    
            };
            sendMail(messagePreparator, emailInfo);
```

Edit: thymeleaf related part:

```
    <img src="cid:pin_image" alt="location" width="25" height="25" border="0"
style="display: block; font-family: Arial; color: #666666; font-size: 14px; width: 25px; height: 25px;">
```

Email body:

[image]

The last image in the email-body is where I set pin_image.
But I get no inline image in my email! I am using using thymeleaf template where I set contentId `pin_image` as in java code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the relevant part of the Thymeleaf template? I would expect to see something like this: `<img src="cid:pin_image">` or `<img th:src="'cid:' + ${pin_image}">`.

Comment: @andrewjames, please check updated question

Comment: Knowing Spring, there's probably more than 1 way to do this - but your code is somewhat different from how I have done this in the past. I did not use `MimeMessagePreparator` - only `MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();`. And I did not use `FileSystemResource` - I used `DataSource res = new FileDataSource("/path/to/pin.png");`. Apart from those, your approach looks the same as mine.

Comment: I tried setting base64 string hardcoded, but that does not work too!  Any hack to solve this? Moreover, will that work for ear file deployment? I mean while reading the image?

Comment: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/northcoder-repo/79d3ef34f23819bcb9eef58c24e6f00b) showing the basics of how I have done this in the past. Never used it in an EAR. No reason to believe it would not work the same way there. Hope this helps! (This was tested using gmail in a browser, by the way).

Comment: How does the email look? Can you include the raw text of the received email?

Comment: @Robert, please check my updated question

Comment: thanks guys, issue resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved just altering the orders of these two lines:

```
 messageHelper.addInline("pin_image",image);
 messageHelper.setText(body, true);
```

I think, I was trying to create an contentId when the HTML is not yet provided. That's why was facing the issue.

**P.S: My whole HTML was in the `body` variable which is my template**